# Twig - ternary conditional operator

Tags: twig, ternary-operator

it's gonna sound very stupid but I don't know how to write this ternary condition within my twig template.

```
 {% for post in posts %}
   <div class="news_text {{ loop.index is odd ? left : right }}">
     {{ post.content }}
   </div>
 {% endfor %}
```

Can anyone tell me what would be the good syntax pls? :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might try doing this the other way.
Create an if and according to the result set output to either left or right.

```
{% for post in posts %}    
    {% set output = "right" %}
    {% if loop.index is odd %}
        {% set output = "left" %}
    {% endif %}
    <div class="news_text {{ output }}">    
{% endfor %}
```

But if you want to do it your way try:

```
{% for post in posts %}
  <div class="news_text {{ loop.index is odd ? "left" : "right" }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Oh perfect Thx! :-)
I prefer the 2nd solution as it's more compact. I had a "fix" using ifs in the mean time but it's not very pretty ^^

Comment: Cool, if it worked for you - make sure to accept my answer

Comment: Oh I didn't know I could do that ^^
Done :-)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `if/else`, there actually exists a **ternary operator** in twig

#### Ternary Operator /  Conditional operator

```
{{ (isTrue) ? 'true' : 'false' }}
```

**Short-hand syntax** is also supported:

```
{{ foo ?: 'no' }} is the same as {{ foo ? foo : 'no' }}
{{ foo ? 'yes' }} is the same as {{ foo ? 'yes' : '' }}
```

[Official Docs](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#other-operators)