# Formatting statements

Tags: twig

Currently I'm using this:

```html
{% if locale == 'pt' %}
<html lang="pt-BR">
{% elseif locale == 'en' %}
<html lang="en-US">
{% endif %}
```

It's decent, but makes the whole `<html>` tag repeat in the source code. What do you think?

In PHP templates I often use this:

```html
<html lang="<?php
if ($locale === 'pt') {
    echo 'pt-BR';
} elseif ($locale === 'en') {
    echo 'en-US';
}
?>">
```

I was wondering if there's a way to produce a similar result with Twig. This is the best I got so far, but it looks a bit odd to me:

```html
<html lang="{%
if locale == 'en'
%}en-US{%
elseif locale == 'pt'
%}pt-BR{%
endif %}"></html>
```

Is there a neater way to do this?

https://twigfiddle.com/4lwsjb

Comment: I don't know Twig but I think this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44697143/twig-ternary-conditional-operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an array/hash to shorten your code:

```
{% set localization = {
    'pt': 'pt-BR',
    'en': 'en-US',
} %}
<html lang="{{ localization[locale]|default('en-US') }}">
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/1oonw5)

---

I would even suggest to just create the localization array in your controller and pass it to the view or register it as a global variable

The default filter I've just added to provide a fallback if the `locale` is unknown in the array

Comment: Thanks. This is definitely neat when you have many locales. In this app of mine, however, there are only 2, so I used the ternary operator, as someone else suggested in a comment:
`<html lang="{{ locale == 'pt' ? 'pt-BR' : 'en-US' }}">`